# Error while updating solr overlay commit settings in solr 7.6.0

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We are using Solr version 7.6.0 in our Solr cluster.

Updates and reads are fine in this cluster but I try to change overlay settings, I get an error: 3 out of 4 the property overlay to be of version 44 within 30 seconds!cluster.

CURL Request:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '{"set-property":{"updateHandler.autoSoftCommit.maxTime":15000}}' http://<IP Address>:8983/api/collections/collectio_name/config
```

Exception Stacktrace:

````
"root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"3 out of 4 the property overlay to be of version 44 within 30 seconds! Failed cores: [http://ip1:8983/solr/collection_name_shard1_replica_n61/, http://ip2:8983/solr/collection_name_shard1_replica_n63/, http://ip3:8983/solr/collection_name_shard1_replica_n69/]",
    "trace":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: 3 out of 4 the property overlay to be of version 44 within 30 seconds! Failed cores: [http://ip1:8983/solr/uk_grocery_catalog_B_shard1_replica_n61/, http://ip12:8983/solr/collection_name_shard1_replica_n63/, http://ip13:8983/solr/collection_name_shard1_replica_n69/]
at org.apache.solr.handler.SolrConfigHandler.waitForAllReplicasState(SolrConfigHandler.java:768)
at org.apache.solr.handler.SolrConfigHandler.access$400(SolrConfigHandler.java:101)
at org.apache.solr.handler.SolrConfigHandler$Command.handleCommands(SolrConfigHandler.java:499)
at org.apache.solr.handler.SolrConfigHandler$Command.handlePOST(SolrConfigHandler.java:345)
at org.apache.solr.handler.SolrConfigHandler$Command.access$100(SolrConfigHandler.java:158)
at org.apache.solr.handler.SolrConfigHandler.handleRequestBody(SolrConfigHandler.java:136)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)
at org.apache.solr.api.ApiBag$ReqHandlerToApi.call(ApiBag.java:242)
at org.apache.solr.api.V2HttpCall.execute(V2HttpCall.java:351)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:515)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:377)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:323)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n",
    "code":500}
    ```
````